# destructor method gets executed without del in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a problem with PyCharm. The Desctructor Method gets executed, without it even been called. If I try it in the Python IDLE the intepreter doesn´t iniatialize the `__del__` method, but in PyCharm it does it

Input:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, nme, ve):
        self.name = nme
        self.velocity = ve
    def __del__(self):
        print("Object", self.name, "got deleted")
    def beschleunigen(self, value):
        self.velocity += value
        self.output()
    def output(self):
        print(self.name, self.velocity, "km/h")

car1 = Vehicle("Ford",40)
car2 = Vehicle("BMW", 45)
    
car1.output()
car2.output()
```

Output:

```
Ford 40 km/h
BMW 45 km/h
Object Ford got deleted
Object BMW got deleted
```

As you can see the `del` function was not even called once and he still executes it

Comment: Is it not just being [garbage collected](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-garbage-collection)?

Comment: Once your program terminates, all objects are garbage collected and their `__del__` method called.

Comment: **`__del__` is not a destructor**. `__del__` is a *finalizer*.

Comment: `del` the keyword **doesn't delete objects**. Python != C++. Python is a memory-managed langauge, you have *no direct control* over the removal of objects from memory. In CPython, this is handled by *reference counting*  as the main garbage collection strategy (with an auxiliary cyclic garbage collector). `del` removes a *name from a namespace*, so it is only indirectly related to `__del__` (because when a reference count goes to zero, an object becomes eligible for garbage collection. In the CPython implementation, it is "freed" immediately when this happens).

Comment: Note, in this particular case, because your objects are alive at the time of interpreter shutdown, `__del__` is not guaranteed to be called. Although it may still be.

Comment: Those dups don't explain the problem. Python calls `__del__` when an object's ref count goes to zero. After your script finishes execution, its a question of whether the thing running the script deleted the namespace holding car1 and car2. In normal script execution, everything in a script's namespace is deleteed and, assuming there weren't circular reference counts, everything gets its `__del__` called. IDLE didn't delete the namespace. It wants to keep those variables around for you. Same thing with  `python3 -i test.py`. The namespace isn't deleted no `__del__` called.

Comment: @tdelaney those dupes explain exactly that, except more accurately. Strictly speaking, `__del__` is called "just before an instance is destroyed", it is a *finalizer*. In CPython, which uses a reference counting garbage collection strategy, this happens when a reference count reaches zero. This may not work like this in, say, Jython or Iron Python implementations. Also, your description about what happens when a script exits is not accurate. `__del__` is *not guaranteed to be called at all* for objects that are still alive when the program terminates and the interpreter shuts down.

Answer (score 1):

Python calls `__del__` when an object's ref count goes to zero. The reference count goes up when an object is assigned to a variable, and down when that assignment is removed.

In your case, `car1` and `car2` are in the script's global namespace. After your script finishes execution, its a question of whether the thing running the script deleted the script's namespace. In normal script execution, everything in a script's namespace is deleted and, assuming there weren't circular reference counts, everything gets its `__del__` called.

```
$ python3 test.py
Ford 40 km/h
BMW 45 km/h
Object Ford got deleted
Object BMW got deleted
```

That's how you ran your script in pycharm. But suppose the namespace isn't deleted? That's what happens with the `-i` option for example. The object's stick around until exit() is called.

```
$ python3 -i test.py
Ford 40 km/h
BMW 45 km/h
>>> print(car1)
<__main__.Vehicle object at 0x7fe3220ebcd0>
>>> exit()
Object Ford got deleted
Object BMW got deleted
```

that's what happened in your IDLE case.

As a side note, `__del__` is not a destructor in the sense of C++. The supposed delete of an object as in `del car1` really just removes the binding of `car1` to its object and decrements the object reference count. Its deleting the variable `car1`, not the object referenced by `car1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!